# Enable additional providers?

Tags: qgis, polygonize, unicodedecodeerror

I try to apply the apply the function of raster to vector from "Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize", but it appears like follows:
*An error has occurred while executing Python code: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", line 88, in onFinished
    self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py", line 208, in onFinished
    msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Python version: 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

QGIS version: 2.18.24 Las Palmas, ff5bd09ab3

*And it asks for add more algorithms to the toolbox,enable additional providers...*
**What can I do?**

Comment: how did you install qgis?

Comment: Does your filename contain non-standard characters? ie: accented characters, UTF-8 characters? Python2.7 has a harder time handling these things than Python3.x.